# Volume key repeat stop working

Tags: keyboard, volume-control

When I hold down an ASCII key on the keyboard, it will repeat.

However, if I hold down the volume function key, it will not repeatedly increment the volume.

How can I fix this? (Ubuntu 16.04 64bit)

Comment: Platform, arch, release version please?

Comment: @user3417815 ups... forgot about most important info

Comment: Do you or did you previously have Microsoft Windows on your laptop? The reason I ask is because it would be interesting to know whether it worked on Windows or any other OS for that matter.

Sometimes when the buttons are seperate from the keyboard, they are set to be pressed rather than held down.

Comment: I can confirm this issue, it was working some weeks ago. Not sure which update broke it.

Comment: Same thing happened to me; I noticed a few days ago. Must be a bug but I'm not sure what's causing it.

Comment: @Sneetsher - It does repeat in both of those cases (though the volume only goes up one notch and still does not).

Comment: @Sneetsher `xev` was the first thing I have checked and yes it is repeating. I am wondering where is this bug : `indicator-sound-service`, `indicator-application-service` ?

Comment: @Sneetsher installed ver: `12.10.2+16.04.20160406-0ubuntu1` , yes proposed are active

Comment: @Sneetsherso so issue  is not in this package, I don't remember but maybe it hasn't been working since fresh install

Comment: @Sneetsher only `indicator-bluetooth` has been updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41334/discussion-between-sneetsher-and-edid).

Comment: @Sneetsher livecd is working as expected, seems `indicator-sound` is not related to this issue.

Comment: Using the `dbus-monitor` I can see that the dbus message to increment volume is not repeated while long pressing the volume button normally. However, the dbus message is repeated if user has opened the taskbar sound menu and long presses the volume button. (16.04 64bit, long pressing used to work.)

Comment: I filed a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1596214

Comment: @AibaraIduas nice (It is not Lenovo issue, I haven't got any)

Comment: This is so unbelievable, this functionality was working for ages and suddenly it is a huge problem to bring it back.

Comment: @EdiD Did the package in proposed not work for you? It's working fine for me in Xenial now.

Comment: @AibaraIduas yes it's working now from proposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Unity bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1586491

Looks like it's fixed and will soon be in Xenial's repository. If you want the fix right now, you can [enable pre-release updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed), then run `sudo apt-get install unity/xenial-proposed`.

Comment: Yeah I saw this. Seems it is fixed in unity 7.5

Answer (score 1):

I meet this problem on my ThinkPad T430 also, if you wanna repeat, you need to click speaker icon first and then long press volume key.

I know it's not a real solution, but it's really work :P

OS:  Ubuntu 16.04 64bit

Kernel:  4.4.0-24-generic

Comment: Surely if you're going to click on the speaker icon first, you may as well just use the volume control there.

Comment: This issue only happened on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS after I upgrade it from 14.04 LTS, not comfortable to use than before.

Comment: When did you exactly upgrade it? In my case it was working on 16.04 some weeks ago.

Comment: In the end of April, date I can't remember

Comment: I have the same issue on Lenovo T440, but I guess I never saw it as a problem.  I suggest this question be taking to Ubuntu directly, seeing as it seems to be, based on comments, a wide spread issue.  What sucks is the loss of your 200 points.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs