# Need to press volume keys multiple times to change volume

Tags: sound, keyboard, 16.04, shortcut-keys, volume-control

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 and have a weird bug that didn't have before. Usually, to change the volume with the shortcuts (fn+f11 or fn+f12) I can either hold fn and press f11/f12 just to change a bit, or hold both fn and f11/f12 to bring the volume all the way down/up.

The problem I'm having is that holding both keys is not working. If I hold both keys it will make the same effect as pressing. In other words, if I want to bring the volume all the way up or all the way down, I need to press f11/f12 multiple times. Which is annoying.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Related http://askubuntu.com/questions/781802/volume-key-repeat-stop-working